# Can I use Geolocation in a React Native unejected Expo Project?

Tags: react-native

The React Native docs give instructions on using Geolocation, but:

> This section only applies to projects made with react-native init or
>   to those made with expo init or Create React Native App which have
>   since ejected.

Is it possible to use geolocation on projects that are still fully running in expo (without having been ejected?

Answer (score 1):

Expo does provide api to get the current location. Please have a look over here[location](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/)